# In ADF We are using Source with REST API which has multiple Object ,how can i fetch filename of multiple object with Same dataset(Sink)

Tags: azure-data-factory

ADF filename with Multiple Object with REST API

For Each object Created a different dataSet(Sink) with Filename

Comment: Please share what you have tried and error if you are facing any? and also share sample input output

Answer (score 0):

> In ADF We are using Source with REST API which has multiple Object ,how can i fetch filename of multiple object with Same dataset(Sink)

- To achieve this first you have to fetch the rest Api objects from web activity(here I used blob storage Api).
  [image]
- Then pass this value to set variable to convert it into an array format `@array(json(activity('Web1').output.Response))`.
  [image]
- Then pass the variable to for each loop
  [image]
- and assess filename from multiple objects in dataset parameter value.
  [image]